# Hide / Show SrartApp ad after the user make a donation / didn't donate

Tags: java, android

I have a **StartApp** ad in the `MainActivity.java`, and a **Donate** option in another activity. I want to hide the ad in the `MainActivity` after the user make a donation from the another activity (Named: `About`). I used `SharedPreferences` to specify whether the user donate or not. But I have a problem with the ad, it doesn't appear even if the user didn't pay!

*** Hint:** *There is no problem with the ad before I added the code below.*

The code below explains how I used the `SharedPreferences`, `hideBanner();` method, etc....

**MainActivity.java:**

```
...
protected SharedPreferences prefs;
    protected static final String PREFS_KEY = "donation";
    private Banner banner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StartAppSDK.init(this, "...", false);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if(prefs.getBoolean("don_ban", true))
        {
            banner = (Banner) findViewById(R.id.startAppBanner);
            if(banner != null)
            {
                banner.hideBanner();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(banner != null)
            {
                banner.showBanner();
            }
        }

...
```

**About.java:**

```
...
protected SharedPreferences prefs;
protected SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

...

private IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener consumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {

            if(result.isSuccess())
            {
                prefs = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("don_ban", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            else
            {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinatorlayout_about), R.string.unknown_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the user donates, you are setting `don_ban` to true. If `don_ban` is true, you hide the banner. The problem is, your default is true when you get `don_ban` from the SharedPreferences. `don_ban` has never been created before the user donates, therefore, will return the default value of `true` and will hide the banner.

Change your code to this and it will work:

```
...
protected SharedPreferences prefs;
    protected static final String PREFS_KEY = "donation";
    private Banner banner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StartAppSDK.init(this, "...", false);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if(prefs.getBoolean("don_ban", false)) //Changed default to false
        {
            banner = (Banner) findViewById(R.id.startAppBanner);
            if(banner != null)
            {
                banner.hideBanner();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(banner != null)
            {
                banner.showBanner();
            }
        }

...
```

All I did was change your if statement's prefs.getBoolean() default to false so it shows the ad by default, instead of hiding it.

Comment: Thanks! In fact I spent 6 hours trying to find the error! Before you post your solution, I didn't know the default value of `boolean` in `SharedPreferences` is `true`! I was thinking it is `false`! So, thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: No problem! If you ever have any more issues, message me and I would be happy to help!